# Longest cycle in a digraph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, optimization

Given a directed graph $G$, we want a (simple) cycle in $G$ of maximal length. The cycle does not need to be an induced subgraph of $G$. What is known about this optimization problem?

Do we know its complexity? Is it much harder than the decision problem of detecting a Hamiltonian cycle? How well-approximable is the problem?

For the exact problem, is there a more efficient algorithm than exhaustive search using Johnson's cycle-enumeration algorithm?

Ideally, for the complexity question, I would like a description similar to [here](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node39.html) and [here](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node114.html) for related problems on undirected graphs: Longest induced cycle, Longest path, and Longest induced path. Longest cycle (for undirected graphs) is discussed in ["A Structural Overview of NP Optimization Problems"](http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/59152), although I have a harder time understanding that account.

FWIW, I'm particularly interested in (approximate) solutions for strongly connected digraphs of 100-500 vertices having average vertex degree ~10 and several induced tournaments on 5-10 vertices. I've been playing with genetic algorithms, and I'd like to know (1) whether better methods are available and (2) what level of performance I can reasonably aim for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By querying for a cycle of each length, your problem is in [F](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp)P<sup>[||](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pparnp)F[NP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp)</sup>.

The following is a reduction from FP<sup>||FNP</sup> to your problem,

If there are no queries then just compute the output. ​ If there's exactly one query then [Connect up the paths](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/sat.pdf) (search for "Connecting up"). ​ Otherwise, for each query, for the [CNF-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) instance representing that query, create a new variable, put that variable into each clause, and create a new clause with just the negation of that variable. ​ Connect up the paths, but instead of putting in the magenta edge on those pages, string those graphs together cyclically by merging each t vertex with an s vertex (from a different query). ​ For each s-t portion, if the cycle traverses the

[variable that wasn't originally in the corresponding CNF-SAT instance] in the False direction,

then [the truth values encoded by its directions along the s-t portion's other chains]

are a witness for the corresponding query, else there are no witnesses for

the corresponding query. ​ Use the resulting witnesses to compute the output.

since

a [cycle that doesn't use any s-t vertex] must stay within a single s-t portion,

whereas a cycle that uses the s-t vertices in their cyclic order can use all of them

and all-but-at-most-one from each s-t portion, so if there's more than one query

then cycles that don't use any s-t vertex can't be longest cycles

 ​ ​ and
a cycle that uses at least one s-t vertex must use them all,

so it must use as many vertices as possible in each s-t portion

 ​ ​ and
for each s-t portion, if the original CNF-SAT representing the corresponding query is satisfiable then there's a path through that portion which uses all of its vertices, else there's

a path through that portion which uses all but one of those vertices (traverse the

[variable that wasn't originally in the CNF-SAT instance] in the False direction)

.
(Thus, your problem is FP<sup>||FNP</sup>-complete.

That reduction goes ​ ​ ​ FP<sup>||FNP</sup> ​ -> ​ [MAX-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) ​ -> ​ your problem ​ .)

For approximation, [this](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=31DF7A6B6D4FA7C2B34FB17504483A48?doi=10.1.1.105.262&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is the main paper, although I'm annoyed

at how they very-nearly show things but don't state them.

Since for a fresh variable h, R($\hspace{.02 in}$g,h,g) will force g to be False, and then such g

can be used everywhere, including in R(+x,g,-x) constraints to force +x and -x

to take on opposite truth values, [wikipedia's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability) induces a reduction from

m-clause n-variable [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) to ((5$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$m)+n+1)-clause ((6$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$m)+(2$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$n)+2)-variable *monotone* 1-in-3 SAT.

By digging through section 7 ("Proof of Proposition 1"), one can see that they have a reduction from the search version of m-clause n-variable *monotone* 1-in-3 SAT to the search version of

((145$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$m)+n+2)-vertex R2VDP with in-degree and out-degree both bounded by 3 which works even if some clause(s) has(ve) more than one of the same variable. ​ ​ ​ (If I'm wrong about the last part

of my previous sentence, then one can just replace R($\hspace{.02 in}$g,h,g) with ​ R(u,g,v) ∧ R(u,v,w) ∧ R(v,g,w) .)

Since one can [$\hspace{.03 in}$just output a cycle for sizes that are at most 3$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$v] and [replace the 2->3 edges

along the bottom of figure 1 with paths that each have at most 2$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$v *internal* vertices],

figure 1 (with each G a copy of the input instance) yields [a reduction from v-vertex R2VDP to digraphs whose number of vertices is *at least three but otherwise arbitrary*] such that, given a

full solution to the R2VDP instance (i.e., one that exhausts all the vertices) one can efficiently

find a Hamiltonian cycle in the output graph, and given [a cycle in the output graph whose

length exceeds 3$\hspace{-0.02 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.02 in}$v] one can efficiently find a not-necessarily-full solution to the R2VDP instance.

Clearly, only the last of the previous paragraph's three sentences (the really-long one) might

yield any meaningful concrete lower bounds for your input sizes. ​ However, one can alternatively reduce from [the modification of 2VDP to promise that if there are any such pairs of paths then there is such a pair of paths that together use *enough* of the vertices] at the cost of replacing ["Hamiltonian cycle" with "cycle that uses *enough* of the vertices"] and ["full" with "full-*enough*"].

In the positive direction:

That paper also [references an algorithm that you should consider]

and [gives an algorithm that you should consider].

You can find both of those by going to the bottom paragraph on the page before section 2.

[Color-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-coding) can efficiently find short-enough cycles. ​ [This paper's](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3026.pdf) algorithm can more-efficiently

find short-enough *paths*, and it seems plausible that either it or one of the algorithms it

references can be modified to find short-enough cycles more efficiently than color-coding.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of finding a longest simple cycle in a digraph is **NP**-hard, since the problem of finding a longest simple cycle in an undirected graph is a special case: you can consider an undirected graph to be a digraph with a symmetric edge relation.  (Longest simple cycle is **NP**-hard since it lets you solve Hamiltonian cycle.)

Comment: The problem of hamiltonian cycle (and path) in directed graphs is NP-complete, all by itself.

Comment: Well, sure, but the problem is usually stated for undirected graphs. The reduction is trivial so I figured I may as well say what it was, rather than just assert its existence.